# Subquery returns more than 1 row i dont know

Tags: sql, subquery, row

When i trying get the "tytul" field i catch this error

```
   SELECT f.*, 
      (SELECT MAX(e) FROM seriale WHERE s = MAX(k.s) AND id_serialu = f.id) as e, 
      MAX(k.s) as s, 
      (SELECT tytul FROM seriale c WHERE c.s = s AND c.e = e) as tytul
   FROM serial f
   LEFT JOIN seriale k ON f.id=k.id_serialu
   GROUP BY f.id
   ORDER BY f.id DESC
   LIMIT 25
```

Comment: This query will return 1 or more row for each row of the serial table. It's impossible to say what is happening and how to correct the query if you do not provide further info. How are serial and seriale related? Why are you adding a LEFT JOIN on seriale and mixing this with SUBSELECTs on the same table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some aliases in your subquery.

```
(SELECT tytul FROM seriale c WHERE c.s = f.s AND c.e = f.e) as tytul
```

If you don't do that, `s` and `e` are sought in the closest scope, which is `c`, so the query then is interpreted as:

```
(SELECT tytul FROM seriale c WHERE c.s = c.s AND c.e = c.e) as tytul
```

This obviously returns more than one row, since it returns everything in the table.

But with the aliases, it will of course only work, if you got at most 1 row per combination of s and e in `seriale`.

Answer (score 0):

When using a Subquery in the select statement that particular subquery should return only 1 row.

For eg : In your query

```
(SELECT MAX(e) FROM seriale WHERE s = MAX(k.s) AND id_serialu = f.id)
```

and

```
(SELECT tytul FROM seriale c WHERE c.s = s AND c.e = e)
```

should return only a single value. It cannot return more than 1 value.